# Google Chrome Developer Tools Network combines network calls together how do you prevent this?

Tags: google-chrome, networking

I don't know exactly when Google Chrome started doing this but it has started combining similar network calls together.  For example a page that looks up words in a dictionary using ajax to a search page say looks at www.dictionary.com  and then the user clicks on other tasks say www.google.com (ajax button)  and www.yahoo.com (ajax button) never leaving the page just sending ajax calls to those pages then hits the dictionary www.dictionary.com (ajax button again) my network panel looks like this

```
   www.dictionary.com
   www.dictionary.com
   www.google.com
   www.yahoo.com
```

so now every time I hit the dictionary button it doesn't populate at the bottom.  I really need to get each action to populate by itself when it happens is it possible to get it to be like it used to and show

```
   www.dictionary.com
   www.google.com
   www.yahoo.com
   www.dictionary.com
```

Thanks for any help.  My next question how to tell StackOverflow links are not code.